# Why doesn't the inclusion $\subseteq$ hold?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A, B, C, D$ be arbitrary sets.

I want to show that $$(A\cup B)\times (C\cup D)\supseteq(A\times C)\cup (B\times D)$$ Give an example so that the real inclusion holds.

I have done the following :

\begin{align*}(x,y)\in (A\times C) \cup (B\times D)  & \Longrightarrow (x,y)\in A\times C \text{ or } (x,y)\in B\times D \\ & \Longrightarrow \left (x\in A\text{ and } y\in C\right ) \text{ or } \left (x\in B\text{ and } y\in D\right )\\ &\overset{ \text{distributive property} }{ \Longrightarrow }\left (x\in A\text{ or } x\in B\right ) \text{ and } \left (y\in C\text{ or } y\in D\right )\\ &\overset{ \text{Def of } \cup }{ \Longrightarrow } x\in A\cup B \text{ and } y\in C\cup D \\ &\overset{\text{Def of } \times}{ \Longrightarrow }(x,y)\in (A\cup B)\times (C\cup D) \end{align*}

Is everything correct and complete?

Why doesn't also the inclusion $\subseteq$ hold?

Comment: Why doesn't also the inclusion ⊆ hold?  Consider an element $(b,c)$ where $b \in B$ and $c \in C$

Comment: You might just try a random example; good chance it will be a counterexample.

Comment: If $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ are four different one-element sets, then it looks to me like $(A\cup B)\times(C\cup D)$ will have $4$ elements, while $(A\times C)\cup(B\times D)$ will have only $2$ elements.

Comment: Consider the cardinalities: if $A,B,C,D$ are disjoint finite sets then $$L:=|(A \cup B) \times (B \cup D)| = (|A| + |B|)(|C|+|D|) = |A||C| + |A||D| + |B||C| + |B||D|$$ but $$R:=|(A \times C) \cup (B \times D)| = |A||C| + |B||D|$$ so in particular $L > R$ (for nonempty sets at least) and thus the left side can never be a subset of the right side.

Comment: If we consider an element $(b,c)$ where $b\in B$ and $c\in C$ (and do we have to consider that the sets $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ are all dinstinct?), then we have that $(b,c)\in (A\cup B)\times (C\cup D)$. But it doesn't hold that $(b,c)\in (A\times C)\cup (B\times D)$, since that would mean that $(b,c)\in A\times C$ or $(b,c)\in B\times D$ but $(b,c)\in A\times C$ cannot hold since $b\notin A$ and $(b,c)\in B\times D$ cannot hold since $c\notin D$. Is everything correct and complete? @ArthurVause

Comment: @MaryStar That's it.

Comment: Great!! Thank you very much!! :-) @ArthurVause

Comment: Thank you!! :-) @bof

Comment: Thank you!! @SV-97